# SELECT rows between two datetimes when the range is dynamic

Tags: database, wpdb, date, select

I'm trying to select rows that fall into a certain date range from my database table. The range is determined dynamically by the user.

In my database I have a column called "dateAndTime". It has dates stored into it in this format:

`2021-06-01 19:37:00`

I'm trying to select the rows with this:

```
function getEventsByDateRange(){

    $eventType = ($_POST["event"]);
    $dateRangeFrom = ($_POST["dateRangeFrom"]);
    $dateRangeTo = ($_POST["dateRangeTo"]);

    $formattedDateRangeFrom = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dateRangeFrom));
    $formattedDateRangeTo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dateRangeTo));

    global $wpdb;

    $eventQueryResults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM dailyevents 
    WHERE dateAndTime BETWEEN {$formattedDateRangeFrom} AND {$formattedDateRangeTo} ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC", ARRAY_A); 

    $jsonEncoded = json_encode($eventQueryResults, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    echo $jsonEncoded;

    exit();

}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
<div id="error"><p class="wpdberror"><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;04:00:00 AND 2021-06-02 03:59:59 ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC&#039; at line 2]<br /><code>SELECT * FROM dailyevents 
    WHERE dateAndTime BETWEEN 2021-06-01 04:00:00 AND 2021-06-02 03:59:59 ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC</code></p></div>[]
```

Comment: That is not specific to WordPress, and you should actually enclose the dates in quotes like so: `BETWEEN '$formattedDateRangeFrom' AND '$formattedDateRangeTo'` ..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can put variable names inside quotes and still have them refer to the variable. Feel free to make this the answer. I thought it is relevant to wordpress since I'm using wpdb->get_results()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error itself is not specific to WordPress, which means even if you used phpMyAdmin or the MySQL command line interface to execute the same query with the dates not enclosed in quotes, you would still get the same error.

Therefore for string literals like the `2021-06-01 04:00:00` ([a `DATETIME` literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)) in the error, you need to enclose the date-time value in single (preferred) or double quotes, e.g. `'2021-06-01 04:00:00'`.

So your query should look like so (* wrapped for brevity):

```php
$eventQueryResults = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT * FROM dailyevents
    WHERE dateAndTime BETWEEN '$formattedDateRangeFrom' AND '$formattedDateRangeTo'
    ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC
", ARRAY_A );
```

And that should work, but now here's something specific to WordPress: It is generally recommended to use [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare a SQL query for *safe* execution, particularly query having dynamic values that are direct input from users or an unknown source.

So with `$wpdb->prepare()`, the above code could be rewritten as:

```php
// I know the variables store a date() value, but this is just to demonstrate
// wpdb::prepare() usage.

$query = $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT * FROM dailyevents
    WHERE dateAndTime BETWEEN %s AND %s
    ORDER BY dateAndTime DESC
", $formattedDateRangeFrom, $formattedDateRangeTo );

$eventQueryResults = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
```

And I thought you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql :)

Also in response to your comment: "*I didn't know you can put variable names inside quotes and still have them refer to the variable.*", you certainly can, just like when echoing something like `echo "value of blah: '$blah'";` — just make sure the variables are accessible, i.e. defined and in scope.